# Certbot - how do i choose a DNS plugin?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, certbot

I am trying to make certbot generate a wildcard certificate, but i am confused about what kind of DNS plugin should i be using and why?

There are quite several listed in here:
https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins

Comment: Reading that page:  Visit [https://certbot.eff.org/](https://certbot.eff.org) to learn the best way to use the DNS plugins on your system. That link should help you choose by selecting the software and system you are running.

Comment: They don't really explain how should i know what plugins to use. They sorta expect us to know from the start. That's why i posted here

Comment: Did you go to the link and select the software and system you are running? That's how you know which one to use.

Comment: Of course. I've done all of that. My question was what do i do next, given i want to make a wildcard certificate

Comment: What software and system are you using to run the website you are trying to generate the certificate on? All of the plugins should be able to generate wildcard certificates - you will need to follow the instructions for the specific plugin the site recommends for your software and system.

Comment: The plugins are independant from software and system. And my question is not how to use the plugins. My questions is how do i know which DNS plugin to use.